# localtime(_r) inversed behavior

Tags: c, linux, localtime

I wrote small program to show local time relative to GMT (or UTC):

```
struct tm l;    
time_t stamp = 1534435540;

// No TZ set
printf("TZ=%s\n",getenv("TZ"));
gmtime_r(&stamp, &l);
printf("UTC: %0u:%0u:%0u - %0u.%0u.%0u\n",l.tm_hour,l.tm_min,l.tm_sec,l.tm_mday,l.tm_mon+1,l.tm_year+1900);
localtime_r(&stamp, &l);
printf("Local: %0u:%0u:%0u - %0u.%0u.%0u\n\n",l.tm_hour,l.tm_min,l.tm_sec,l.tm_mday,l.tm_mon+1,l.tm_year+1900);

// Positive TZ: east to Greenwich (e.g. China)
setenv("TZ", "UTC+6:00", 1);    
printf("TZ=%s\n",getenv("TZ"));     
tzset();    
gmtime_r(&stamp, &l);
printf("UTC: %0u:%0u:%0u - %0u.%0u.%0u\n",l.tm_hour,l.tm_min,l.tm_sec,l.tm_mday,l.tm_mon+1,l.tm_year+1900);
localtime_r(&stamp, &l);
printf("Local: %0u:%0u:%0u - %0u.%0u.%0u\n\n",l.tm_hour,l.tm_min,l.tm_sec,l.tm_mday,l.tm_mon+1,l.tm_year+1900);

// Negative TZ: west to Greenwich (e.g. US/Canada)
setenv("TZ", "UTC-6:00", 1);    
printf("TZ=%s\n",getenv("TZ"));
tzset();    
gmtime_r(&stamp, &l);
printf("UTC: %0u:%0u:%0u - %0u.%0u.%0u\n",l.tm_hour,l.tm_min,l.tm_sec,l.tm_mday,l.tm_mon+1,l.tm_year+1900);
localtime_r(&stamp, &l);
printf("Local: %0u:%0u:%0u - %0u.%0u.%0u\n\n",l.tm_hour,l.tm_min,l.tm_sec,l.tm_mday,l.tm_mon+1,l.tm_year+1900);
```

Output of this program is the following:

```
TZ=<null>
UTC: 16:5:40 - 16.8.2018
Local: 16:5:40 - 16.8.2018

TZ=UTC+6:00
UTC: 16:5:40 - 16.8.2018
Local: 10:5:40 - 16.8.2018

TZ=UTC-6:00
UTC: 16:5:40 - 16.8.2018
Local: 22:5:40 - 16.8.2018
```

It looks strange, isnt'it? According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone):

> For example, if the time being described is one hour ahead of UTC (such as the time in Berlin during the winter), the zone designator would be "+01:00", "+0100", or simply "+01"

So GMT+6 means that I add 6 hours to GMT to get local time.

But [this article about TZ variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) says the opposite:

> This is positive if the local time zone is west of the Prime Meridian and negative if it is east.

Do I miss something or linux behaves opposite to standard?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104088/why-does-tz-utc-8-produce-dates-that-are-utc8)

Comment: Blame the Unix creators in America. They didn't like their timezone offsets being negative.

Comment: @IanAbbott Could also create the UNIX creators for using an international concept of time, like GMT, rather than setting systems time  to local time like [DOS](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/mswish/ut-rtc.html).

Comment: @chux I suppose, but what sort of idiot would make system time subject to DST changes? Also, a UNIX system is multi-user, and the users could be in different time-zones.

Comment: It's even slightly more confusing these days, as some of the Olsen style timezone identifiers have numeric abbreviations, and the sign of the numeric abbreviation matches ISO 8601, not the sign of the POSIX TZ offsets.

Answer (score 5):

Unix creators used the opposite sign convention in the `TZ` environment variable compared to how time zones are described elsewhere, including in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

That Unix quirk was standardized in [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), and that's the standard Linux follows.

So yes, if you want to set timezone to UTC-04:00 (say, EDT, or Eastern Daylight Time for those somewhere in eastern Canada or US), you can set TZ to `UTC+04:00`.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know